# XmlReader.Create error "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel"

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, github, xmlreader

On my ASP.net-based website I am aggregating feeds of my activities from several website.
One of those is the GitHub feed at `https://github.com/lucamauri.atom`: this is a valid feed correctly readable using a web browser and it properly worked on my website since a couple of weeks ago. Since then, it started generating errors

In the code I first create and `XMLReader` and then I load it in a `SyndicationFeed` object as follows:

```
Dim TempReader As System.Xml.XmlReader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(TempString)
Dim SyndFeed As SyndicationFeed = SyndicationFeed.Load(TempReader)
Dim TempItems As New List(Of SyndicationItem)
TempItems.AddRange(SyndFeed.Items.ToList.GetRange(0, Math.Min(CurrentFeed.TotalElements, SyndFeed.Items.Count)))
```

This works properly with several feeds, but the GitHub one now generate a TLS error on the **first** row of the above code:

> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
>   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetNonFileStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy)
>   at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy)
>   at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
>   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.FinishInitUriString() at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl..ctor(String uriStr, XmlReaderSettings settings, XmlParserContext context, XmlResolver uriResolver)
>   at System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings.CreateReader(String inputUri, XmlParserContext inputContext)
>   at System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(String inputUri, XmlReaderSettings settings, XmlParserContext inputContext)
>   at System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(String inputUri)

I use the same code with other HTTPS feeds (`https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/69295` just to name one) and I do not get the error. So this is something specific to the GitHub feed, but then again I can reach it from a browser on the same machine where I run the website, so I am lost at it.

Any idea on the cause of the issue?

Comment: Are you using a .Net framework version below 4.5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The server is in control of the protocol that is ultimately negotiated. The Stackoverflow server is requiring only TLS v1 as shown in the wireshark capture below. This trace was done on .Net framework version 4.

The Github feed refuses anything below TLS v1.2 and therefore fails on .Net 4.0 because that version is not available by default.

[image]

You can work around it by setting the SecurityProtocol on the ServicePointManager, **if you have .Net 4.5+ installed on the same computer**. If you don't, then you simply cannot make the request.

You do this by using the numeric value for the SecurityProtocol instead of the enumeration value which is not available on .Net 4.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = DirectCast(3072, SecurityProtocolType)
```

[image]

Having done this, you can now negotiate TLS 1.2 even on .Net 4.
However, if you can, just upgrade to a newer framework version to make it easy.

> Update

There is a patch available for .Net 3.5:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3154520/support-for-tls-system-default-versions-included-in-the-net-framework

Comment: `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = DirectCast(3072, SecurityProtocolType)` works like a charm in my project, so this is definitely the right solution. Thanks a lot for your deep investigation.

Comment: SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 - instead of DirectCast

Comment: @Jimmyt1998 That only works on . Net4.5+. Before that there was no enumeration value for Tls12.

Answer (score 2):

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

.NET 4.5.1

Set this in startup class of mvc project and xmlreader worked on https links, thanks guys.